# Draw multiple multi-qubit gates in qcircuit

Tags: diagrams, qcircuit

I am trying to draw 4 three-qubit gates in qcircuit but I already got stuck in my second three-qubit gate and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
\Qcircuit @C=2em @R=.5em {
& \multigate{2}{U_1} & \qw & \mulitgate{2}{U_2}\qw\\
& \ghost{U_1}        & \qw & \ghost{U_2}\qw \\
& \ghost{U_1}        & \qw & \ghost{U_2} \qw
}
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: What is your minimal working example? Please can you put a whole code and not a fragment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you made a typo the second time you wrote `\multigate`.  You probably also want an ampersand before the final `\qw` on each line.

Comment: This is more in the nature of a comment than an answer.  It's kind of thin, and some readers are likely to recommend that it be deleted, even though it is useful and on-topic.

Comment: It is thin, but this seemed like the appropriate level of detail for the question.